# Removing listener from inside outer function

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events, addeventlistener

Is it possible in JS to remove a listener from inside of a function described elsewhere and then passed to the listener?

I expect something like this to work, but it doesn't (I mean the line `self.removeEventListener("blur", named, false);`). At the same time in debugging mode I see that `this` value is passed correctly.

```
someElement.addEventListener("blur", function namedFunc() {handler(this)} ,false);

function handler(self) {
    self.removeEventListener("blur", namedFunc, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *name* `namedFunction` is only visible [inside that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression). Because of that you'd need to pass it to the handler, so that it can be removed later.

```js
var someElement = document.getElementById('foo');

someElement.addEventListener('click', function namedFunc() {
    handler(this, namedFunc);
}, false);

function handler(self, fn) {
    alert('handler called');
    self.removeEventListener('click', fn, false);
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">click me!</button>
```

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could broaden the scope of namedFunc

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, I've been searching for the explanation for some time now:)

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for the answer, but how one can broaden the scope in such context?

Comment: @Dronich If the function would be accessible any other way you could use that to remove it as a listener. E.g. have it stored in a variable somewhere or make it a *real* function not a function expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can broaden the scope of your handler.

See [Yoshi's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010234/227299) for a good explanation of the problem.

```
(function() {
  var someElement = document.getElementById('foo');

  // This function is visible anywhere in the IIFE
  // http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/
  function handler(e) {
    alert('handler called');
    someElement.removeEventListener(handler);
  }
  someElement.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
})();
```

Note that what you are doing can be abstracted

```
function listenOnce(el, eventName, handler)  {
   var wrapper = function(e) {
       handler.apply(this, arguments);
       el.removeEventListener(eventName, wrapper);
   }
   el.addEventListener(eventName, wrapper, false);
}

listenOnce( document.getElementById('foo'), 'click', function() {
  alert('handler called');
});
```